# Origen test_ids next in range accept a Proc/Lambda?

Tags: origen-sdk

I am working with the Origen [test_ids gem 'next in range' feature](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/test_ids#next-in-range-beta-feature).  When I setup the softbin configuration in the test interface I find out dynamically how many different hardbins have a unique softbin range.  This is known but it varies depending on the test module being tested.  Some test modules may have 3 hardbin to softbin combinations and some have 5.  Is it possible to pass a Proc/Lambda to the softbin config shown below?

```
  config.softbins needs: :bin do |options|
    if options[:bin] == 1
      TestIds.next_in_range((1000..2000))
    elsif options[:bin] == 11
      TestIds.next_in_range((10000..99999))
    end
  end
```

Such that the number of `elsif` statements, the bin and the softbin range are all dynamically stitched together.  I know `eval` could work but it seems to be frowned upon.

**EDIT**

OK after reviewing Ginty's answer I tried the solution but it seems like the options are not getting passed into the `next_in_range` method.  Here is the config:

```
            TestIds.configure current_test_insertion do |config|
              config.bins.include << binning_obj.configs(:all).hbin
              config.softbins needs: :bin do |options|
                bin_map = Hash[test_type_hardbins.zip(binning_test_types)]
                TestIds.next_in_range(bin_map[options[:bin]])
              end
              config.send_to_ate = false
            end
```

Here is the error:

```
COMPLETE CALL STACK
-------------------
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
/users/user/origen/github/test_ids/lib/test_ids.rb:236:in `next_in_range'
```

When I pass in the options as so:

```
TestIds.next_in_range(bin_map[options[:bin]], options)
```

I get this error:

```
COMPLETE CALL STACK
-------------------
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  tap
/users/user/origen/github/test_ids/lib/test_ids/allocator.rb:45:in `range_item'
/users/user/origen/github/test_ids/lib/test_ids/allocator.rb:32:in `next_in_range'
```

Given that the [docs say this feature is in beta](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/test_ids#next-in-range-beta-feature), should I move this to a Github issue?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining a softbin with a block, you have complete freedom to put whatever you want in the block, so adding an additional Proc into the equation doesn't make sense to me.

There are effectively two APIs here that you can combine, one is the ability to define a function to work out the number:

```ruby
config.softbins do |options|
  # Put any logic you like in here, return the number at the end
end
```

The other API is the ability to have TestIds keep track of a position in a range:

```ruby
TestIds.next_in_range((1000..2000))
```

You can use that, or not, within your block however you wish.

That you should give you full freedom to define whatever rules you like:

```ruby
config.softbins needs: bin do |options|
  if Time.now.tuesday?
    bin_map = { 5: (1..10), 11: (11..20) }
  else
    bin_map = { 6: (10..20), 12: (21..30) }
  end
  TestIds.next_in_range(bin_map[options[:bin]])
end
```

Note that if you refer to the same `next_in_range` within different branches then they will both consume from the same set of numbers.

If you wanted them to each independently count within that range, then you would need to setup different configurations so that they each have their own database:

```ruby
if Time.now.tuesday?
  TestIds.configure :rule1 do |config|

  end
else
  TestIds.configure :rule2 do |config|

  end
end
```